# Check for value in Mysql if else update value

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, if-statement

I have a database with some columns named UPC title Description and Quantity. i am trying to do a check to see if a UPC number already exists in the column and IF IT DOES then update the quantity of that entry by 1 here is what i have so far:

```
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
                connection.Open();
                MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tableName " +
                           "(upc, title, description, quantity) " +
                       "VALUES " +
                           "(@upc, @title, @description, @quantity)";
                MySqlCommand upcCheck = connection.CreateCommand();
                upcCheck.CommandText = "Select COUNT (*) FROM tableName WHERE " +
                    "(upc=@upc) LIMIT 1";
                upcCheck.Parameters.AddWithValue("@upc", upc.Text); //Checks for duplicate UPCs
                MySqlDataReader check = upcCheck.ExecuteReader();
                    if( check.Read() != false)
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity",++); //not sure how to word it right
                    }


                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@upc", upc.Text); //adding parameters SAFELY to the statement
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", titlename);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", descname);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", "1");

                MySqlDataReader result = command.ExecuteReader();
```

I'm just not sure how to word it to do the check.

UPDATE! Here is the working code.

```
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);

                connection.Open();
                MySqlCommand updatecommand = connection.CreateCommand();

                updatecommand.CommandText = "UPDATE tableName Set quantity = quantity +1 " +
                    "WHERE upc = @upc";
                updatecommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@upc", upc.Text);
                using (MySqlDataReader updateResult = updatecommand.ExecuteReader())
                {


                    if (updateResult.RecordsAffected == 0)
                    {
                        affected = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        affected = false;
                    }
                }
                 if(affected == true)
                {

                    MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tableName " +
                        "(upc, title, description, quantity) " +
                    "VALUES " +
                        "(@upc, @title, @description, @quantity)";
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@upc", upc.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", titlename);//adding parameters SAFELY to the statement
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", descname);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", "1");



                    MySqlDataReader result = command.ExecuteReader();
                }
```

Comment: You can actually use an *upsert* for this - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsert

Comment: so if i do an upsert INSTEAD of an insert or update it will do either or?

Comment: Yup, replace both your statements with a single upsert.  The logic is "insert this if it doesn't exist, otherwise update the row instead."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I've not worked specifically with MySqlDataReader, I would slightly change the queries around... the otherwise format (parameterization) you have for the insert is completely fine.

Although the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE provided by Hristo is cool, you would be missing the other column elements for your record.  I would change to..

```
MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "UPDATE tableName Set Quantity = Quantity +1 " +
                           "WHERE upc = @upc"
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@upc", upc.Text);
```

** Dont know how the value / status will be returned from the MySqlDataReader, but

```
result = command.ExecuteReader();

if( the status indicates it actually succeeded in an update, 
    or how many records were updated > 0 )
  return;  // you've just increased the counter...
```

OTHERWISE, it was not on file.. continue with the rest of your SQL-insert command, we can overwrite the last command instance...

```
command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tableName " +
                           "(upc, title, description, quantity) " +
                       "VALUES " +
                           "(@upc, @title, @description, @quantity)";

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@upc", upc.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", titlename);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", descname);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", "1");

result = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Yours looks like it would work but what is the syntax to check if the update succeeded? that is the only part i'm cloudy on. any help from anyone else on this solution?

Comment: I DID IT! i did:

        if(updateResult.RecordsAffected ==0)
{do the rest of the insert}

Comment: ran into a problem but i got it fixed. i will edit code in Original post shortly to reflect how to do it

Comment: @DevinPrejean, glad I was able to help guide without the EXACT syntax solution, many times just that little nudge looking at a task differently can put you on the track.  Now, your comment about "updateResults.RecordsAffected" could help someone else too (in addition to me in possible future).

Answer (score 1):

If UPC is you primary key you can use `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` functionality of MySQL database. If you dont want to `INSERT` the new `UPC` just run an `UPDATE` query if there is no such row if wont affect the data in the table.

```
UPDATE <tablename> SET quantity=quantity+1 WHERE UPC='<upc>'
```

Comment: that won't work because then it will update if its there. and if it is then it will insert another also the UPC is NOT the primary can i do that without it being a primary key?

Comment: That's it is on duplicate key if there isn't i t will insert, if you only use the standard update statement it should do what you want: to increment the quantity if the poduct exists in the database. Have I undurstand your question

Comment: If you have only unique values for UPC than UPDATE <tablename> SET quantity=quantity+1 WHERE UPC='<upc>' should do your job. Otherwise it will update more than one rows.

Comment: so just an update will ALSO insert or do i have to do the "INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" that you listed earlier

Comment: NO UPDATE only updates the information just do the UPDATE query (NO INSERT UPDATE doest not INSERT). And if I can suggest you to take a brief look at some MySQL tutorials, about basic queries, you leave the impression that you are in the beggining of MySQL

Comment: i wouldn't say beginning, i've done alot of mysql with PHP but never heard of this "upsert" or on duplicate key stuff. sorry for the newb question. I'll try working on it for a little bit Thanks for the help @hristo

Comment: It's ok we are all here to help each other. Didn't mind to make you feel bad.